# Audio Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, speakers, class-d

We are using [WM8960](http://www.sunnyqi.com/upLoad/product/month_1306/WM8960.pdf) Audio CODEC which has internal Class D Amplifier with up to 1W output for speakers. I plan to provide external Class D amplifier as optional which boost up the output power to 2W for our prototype build and testing. Is it the right way to do it? It's very new to me.

Comment: With the same speakers? I mean, while the chip is driving the speakers with up to 1W output, you want to activate the external amplifier to boost the output power **to the same speakers**. Am I right? Or, are you planning to use the external amplifier with extra speakers? Also, do you want to disable the on-chip audio output?

Comment: yes same speaker. Stereo 8/4 ohms. Audio CODEC--> External amplifier --> Speaker connector this the flow. But even though I am worried about Audio codec internal amplifier will make any issue when using External Amplifier. Because i am taking Speaker +/- from audio codec and connect ext amp In+ and In- .

Comment: 2 watts compared to 1 watts into a speaker is 3 dB more output and about 30% louder (i.e. not much louder) so, my question to you is, why would you go to all the trouble of adding an amplifier that only produces a bit more sound volume to the ear?

Comment: Hi Andy,  I would like to ask my doubt in simple way, Our Audio codec has Speaker out lines (Stereo). shall I connect this SPK out as input of the 5W class D differentail Amplifier input?